# Why is this only printing the last word?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having a really hard time debugging this. When I try to print out the structures I only get the last word. Am I writing over the memory or something? Can someone help me?

```
typedef struct hash_table_ {
  void **order;
  int *number_next_calls;
  int *number_buckets;
  int *buckets_size;
  int *worst;
  int *total;
  float *average;
  int (*hash_func)(char *);
  data_el **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

typedef struct data_{
  char *key;
  void *data;
  struct data_ *next;
}data_el;

main(){

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((c == ' ') || (c == ',') || (c == '.') || (c == '!') || (c == '"') ||
        (c == ':') || (c == '\n')) {

      /* End of a word */
      if (char_index) {
        /* Word is not empty */
        word[char_index] = '\0';
        lower_case_word(word);
        if(!find_hash(dictionary,word) ){
          insert_hash(dictionary,word,frequency[hash_function(word)]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[hash_function(word)] -> key);
        printf("%d \n",hash_function(word));
        frequency[hash_function(word)]++;
        char_index = 0;
        num_words++;
      }
    }else{
      word[char_index++] = c;
    }
  }

/*This is when it prints*/
  printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[337] -> key);
  printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[532] -> key);
  printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[93] -> key);

 }

 int hash_function(char *word){

  int sum,i;
  i = 0;
  sum = 0;
  while(word[i] != '\0'){
    sum = sum + word[i];
    i++;
  }
  return sum%1000;
}

void insert_hash(Phash_table table, char *key, void *data){
  int index;
  data_el *p, *cur;

  index = table -> hash_func(key);

  /*Head insertion*/
  if(table -> buckets_array[index] == NULL){
    table -> buckets_array[index] = (data_el *)malloc(sizeof(data_el));
    table -> buckets_array[index] -> data = data;
    table -> buckets_array[index] -> next =  NULL;
    table -> buckets_array[index] -> key = key;
  }else{
    printf("%s",table -> buckets_array[index] -> key);
    cur = table -> buckets_array[index];
    p = (data_el *)malloc(sizeof(data_el));
    p -> key = key;
    p -> data = data;
    p -> next = cur;
    cur = p;
    /*
    table -> buckets_array[index] = cur;
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, please isolate the problem to some specific part of the program, you should use a debugger or print statements for it, and you should also provide a sample input and output (expected and actual) to help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Well when I'm in the while function I used the printf to see the data that it is storing and it is printing what is just scanned in, which is correct. After it is done with the while loop, I tried printing it `printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[337] -> key);
  printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[532] -> key);
  printf("%s\n", dictionary -> buckets_array[93] -> key);` But it is just giving me the last of that it scanned in.

Comment: Stylistic note: operator precedence sometimes works in your advantage: `*(table -> total) = *(table -> total) + 1;` can be written is `*table -> total = *table -> total + 1;`, which can be further reduced to `*table->total += 1;` The `->` binds very tight!. Similar for `(table -> buckets_size[index]) = (table -> buckets_size[index]) + 1;` -->> `table ->buckets_size[index] += 1;`

Comment: The `int hashfunction()` will sometimes return negative values, which will naively be used as an array index. Danger, Will Robinson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insert_hash` you have

```
table -> buckets_array[index] -> key = key;
```

resp

```
p -> key = key;
```

that is, you let the bucket entry point to the same memory that got passed from `main`. The code is incomplete, so I can't be sure, but I bet that it `main` you reuse the `word` array and don't allocate a new one after each insertion. So the contents of the string pointed to by `table->buckets_array[index]->key` gets overwritten.

You have to copy the strings to a new chunk of memory and let the bucket entries point to that.